# Disable logs from imported module using the root logger

Tags: python, logging, python-import

One of Microsoft's `presidio-analyzer` [modules](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/blob/master/presidio-analyzer/presidio_analyzer/recognizer_registry/recognizer_registry.py#L151) logs with the root logger:

```py
        logging.info(
            "Returning a total of %d recognizers (predefined + custom)", len(to_return)
        )
```

This particular line will be written millions of times.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/issues/372) on GitHub, but in the meantime, is there a way to suppress these logs? I can't access the logger by name, and I can't set the root logger to `WARN` either because it propagates to all my loggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patch the import of logging in that specific module, like so:

```
import microsoft_module

microsoft_module.logging = my_fake_logging
```

Than you can proxy all the calls with the desired level to the actual ligging module.

Note not to patch `microsoft_module.logging.info` directly, for it will affect all logging, since it's the same module used.

**Update:** I tried to mess around with the concept a bit, and here's what I came up with:

You can patch the globals in a specific function, that way you can change logging in that specific scope!

```
x = 5

def g():
    print(x)

g() 

print(g.__globals__)
g.__globals__['x'] = 9

g()
```

Output:

```
5
{'__name__': '__main__', '__file__': '/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__warningregistry__': {'version': 0}, 'x': 5, 'g': <function g at 0x755125edc0>}
9
```

Comment: Patching an imported module, I would not have thought of that! That's already an upvote, now let me try... :)

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks! For the record, it was actually a sub-module, so I had to do `from presidio_analyzer.recognizer_registry import recognizer_registry` and then patch the logging.